# Flask application: Using gunicorn on ECS Fargate , How to

Tags: flask, gunicorn, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

**Info**:

- I created a flask app and on my Dockerfile last command `CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --access-logfile - "app:create_app()"`
- I build,tag and upload image on ECR
- I used this docker image to create an ECS Fargate instance with the following configs (just posting the one needed for the question):

```
ECSTaskDefinition: 
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition  
  Properties:  
    Cpu: "256"  
    Memory: "1024"  
    RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: contained_above
            .
            .
            .
```

```
ECSService:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  DependsOn: ListenerRule
  Properties:
    Cluster: !Sub "${EnvName}-ECScluster"
    DesiredCount: 1
    LaunchType: FARGATE
    DeploymentConfiguration:
      MaximumPercent: 200
      MinimumHealthyPercent: 50
    NetworkConfiguration:
      AwsvpcConfiguration:
        AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
        Subnets:
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${EnvName}-PUBLIC-SUBNET-1"
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${EnvName}-PUBLIC-SUBNET-2"
        SecurityGroups:
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${EnvName}-CONTAINER-SECURITY-GROUP"
      ServiceName: !Sub "${EnvName}-ECS-SERVICE"
      TaskDefinition: !Ref ECSTaskDefinition
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: contained_above
          ContainerPort: 5000
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
```

(App is working normally)

**Question**

Now my question is what number should be the workers on gunicorn command (my last command in dockerfile)?

On [gunicorn design](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers) it is stated to use `Generally we recommend (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the number of workers to start off with.`

So whats the number of cores on a fargate? Does actually make sense to combine gunicorn with Fargate like the above process? Is there 'compatibility' between loadbalancers and gunicorn workers? What is the connection between `DesiredCount` of ECS Service and the gunicorn `-w` workers value? Am I missing or miss-understanding something?

**Possible solution(?)**

One way that I could call it is the following:

```
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w $(( 2 * `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id' | wc -l` + 1 )) --access-logfile - "app:create_app()"
```

But I am not sure if that would be a good solution.
Any insights? Thanks

Comment: Have you discovered anything?

Comment: While this doesn't necessarily answer your question in regards to Gunicorn, here's a SO answer which could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137239/2602267

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I'm using a configuration file for gunicorn to use when starting:
`gunicorn.conf.py`

```py
import multiprocessing


bind = "0.0.0.0:8080"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
worker_class = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornH11Worker"
keepalive = 0
```

you can tell gunicorn which config file to use with the `--config` flag.

Sadly I can't find the source anymore, but I've read that 4-12 workers should be enough to handle hundreds if not thousands of simultaneous requests - depending on your application structure, worker class and payload size.
Do take this with a grain of salt tho, since I can't find the source anymore, but it was in an accepted SO answer from a well-reputated person if I remember correctly.

[Offical gunicorn docs state somthing in the 2-4 x $(NUM_CORES)range](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-processes).
Another option would be as [gunicorn docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#how-many-workers) state at another point:

> Generally we recommend (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the number of workers
> to start off with. While not overly scientific, the formula is based
> on the assumption that for a given core, one worker will be reading or
> writing from the socket while the other worker is processing a
> request.
>
> Obviously, your particular hardware and application are going to
> affect the optimal number of workers. Our recommendation is to start
> with the above guess and tune using TTIN and TTOU signals while the
> application is under load.

So far I've been running well with holding true to the 4-12 worker recommendation. My company runs several APIs, which connect to other APIs out there, which results in mostly 1-2seconds request time, with the longest taking up to a whole minute (a lot of external API calls here).

Another colleague I talked to mentioned, they are using 1 worker per 5 simultaneous requests they expect - with similar APIs to ours. Works fine for them as well.

Comment: Source of the 4-12 workers comment: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#how-many-workers